# Two tensor product norms inducing different topologies on the space of simple tensors

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, tensor-products

Are  there two  Normed  spaces $V,W$ for  which the  algebraic tensor  product $V\otimes W$   admits two  different norms, both satisfying  $\parallel x \otimes y \parallel= \parallel x \parallel. \parallel y \parallel$,  but the topologies they induce on the space of simple tensors $\{x \otimes y \mid x\in V,\;y\in W\}$ are non homeomorphic?

Can this be happened  when $V,W$  are $C^{*}$  algebras and the two norms are $C^{*}$  algebra norms.